# Remapping Function Keys for media vs. Alt + Function Key for specific app

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, media-keys, alt

I have an HP Laptop and I finally got around to changing the BIOS setting to reverse the annoying <kbd>Fn</kbd>+Function Key "feature" since I regularly <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd> & <kbd>F11</kbd> with VBA & Office (a lot more often than I need to change screen brightness, etc)...

People can do whatever they want with their function keys behind closed doors, but mine were finally back to being **real function keys**, as God intended.

However I missed having the convenience of the function keys that acted as **Media Keys** to control VLC, Winamp & Spotify: 
<kbd><sup>F6</sup> ⏪</kbd><kbd><sup>F7</sup> ▶</kbd><kbd><sup>F8</sup> ⏩</kbd><kbd><sup>F9</sup> -</kbd><kbd><sup>F10</sup> +</kbd><kbd><sup>F11</sup></kbd>

So I installed [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) to remap some of them *back* to the HP defaults:

```
F6::Media_Prev
F7::Media_Play_Pause
F8::Media_Next
F9::Volume_Down
F10::Volume_Up
```

This works but I would like to use <kbd>F11</kbd> for *both* `Volume_Mute` **and** to open the VBE window in Access/Excel (normally <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> functionality).

---

- Is there a way (with *or* without AutoHotKey) to set it up so that the key will behave differently depending on which window is active?

  > If **`ActiveWindow`** is {***Excel*** or ***Access***} then:
  >
  > **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>** *remains as* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
  >
  > If *any other* window us active then:
  >
  > **<kbd>F11</kbd>** **⇒** <sub>AutoHotKey:</sub> **`Volume_Mute`**
- if that's *not* possible, what would my script look like to map like:

  > **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>** *remains as* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
  >
  > <sup>and</sup>
  >
  > **<kbd>F11</kbd>** **⇒** <sub>AutoHotKey:</sub> **`Volume_Mute`**

There's another change or two I'm debating, but with an answer to this, I should be able to figure out the rest.  Thanks!

<sub>`(HP Folio 13 Windows 7 64bit)`</sub>

Comment: You can make a hotkey definition context-sensitive by using the [#If](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm) or the [#IfWinExist/#IfWinActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directive.

Comment: I agree, AutoHotKey can check for a window title, and so an AutoHotkey script should be able to have a condition that provides the flexibility needed to accomplish the desired goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an #If statement to selectively enable a hotkey. You can change the WinTitle if you like as well.

```
#If Not (WinActive ("ahk_exe excel.exe") Or WinActive ("ahk_exe access.exe"))
F11::Volume_Mute
#IfWinActive ; make sure all hotkeys after this are not qualified with the above #If statement
```